# Software to drag and drop ID3 tags into MP3s?

Tags: mp3, tags, id3

A while back I **ripped a load of CDs into individual MP3s** for each track. Like a fool I didn't use [CDEx](http://cdexos.sourceforge.net/) (for CDDB lookups) or an equivalent when ripping so there are **no ID3 tags** and each track is named 'track 1', 'track 2', etc. without any idea of the real track names. However, the tracks are stored in directories named according to album.

Does anyone know of a tool to do a CDDB lookup for an album that would allow me to drag and drop the details into each MP3? Or better still, do it all for me? I know I'm asking a lot.

PS> I'm using XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) is a good way to do bulk tagging. Its a one trick horse but its amazingly intuitive and can be automated.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried and did exactly what I need - thanks. How can software be this intuitive? ;)

Answer (score 3):

One solution could be to use a program like [Media Monkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com).

It allows multiple selection of tracks (after they've been added to the library), so you can select the entire album and enter data such as the album title, artist, genre and date etc. in one go.

Then set the track name (and possibly rename the file itself) select "Tools > Auto-tag from Web..." to look it up from the web. Actually this will look up all the properties so this might be best done first.

Answer (score 1):

[Mediamonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/) is great at tagging. It can get tags from web services (Amazon and others). It can also rename the actual files based on the track names. At the least it can bulk rename based on your input- as in select all tracks in an album, and you can rename all the artist/album details.

I've been playing around with it recently and am amazed by what it can do. Also supports scripts to download for other clever purposes.